# Free games on PlayStation Network and PlayStation Plus

Tags: ps3, psn, ps4

I'll be buying my 2nd game console this season since PSX, and I'm leaning towards PS3. PS4 won't be available until early next year because of stock constraints.

Just a couple of questions or so before I finalize everything.

1. Are there still free games on PSN?
2. If you go online with PSN, can you join a PS+ (eg Ghost) online game?
3. If you buy a game with PS+, can you still play online?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PS+ subscription comes "on top" of the usual (free) PSN subscription, you're not restricted to playing with members of either group of users by being a member of one group or the other (PS4 games can **only** be played online if you're a PS+ subscriber, though).

The games offered through PS+ "Instant Game Collection" are exactly the same as their "full priced" counterparts, meaning they have all of their features intact, including online play. If you got a game for free through PS+, you'll be able to play it as long as your PS+ subscription still hasn't expired; If you bought it with a PS+ discount, it's yours to keep forever.

One exception worth noting with PS+ is that a couple of free games offered have only their "single player" component included. These are "Uncharted 3" & "Starhawk". The online component for these games can be bought separately.